# Same code giving runtime error if i am using bufferedreader instead of scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {//BigInteger bi1, bi2, bi3;  
    long t,j,n;
    int i,x;

    BigInteger u,sum,temp,m;
    BigInteger[] a=new BigInteger[100009];  long[] b=new long[100009];
    long mm=1000000007,f;
        Scanner har=new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));           

        t=har.nextInt();
        for(f=0;f<t;f++)
        {   temp = BigInteger.valueOf(1);   sum = BigInteger.valueOf(0);    u = BigInteger.valueOf(0);              

                n=har.nextInt();    x=har.nextInt(); m=har.nextBigInteger();//String line = br.readLine();
    //String line = br.readLine(); // to read multiple integers line
        //String[] strs = line.trim().split("\\s+");
 //String[] s1 = br.readLine().split(" ");
 //StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
                for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
                {b[i]=har.nextInt();                

// b[i] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
//b[i] = Long.parseLong(System.console().readLine());    
//b[i]=Long.parseLong(s1[i-1]);
                }
        }
    }
}

input is of form 
t
n x m
a[1] a[2] a[3] .......a[n]
```

This code is running correctly for scanner but if i try to use buffered reader or string tokenizer it is giving runtime error .
I am new to java and i need to use big integer for further part of the question.

Comment: What runtime error do you get? Please share the stack trace.

Comment: i am getting null point exception error in //StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());

Comment: could you give us the different codes, i.e. one with scanner and one with bufferedreader so we can test ? The comments don't really make sense.

Comment: You are getting the error because there would be no line to read and hence `br.readLine()` returns `null`.

Comment: http://ideone.com/pDxQ81 -> giving run time error for set of inputs  http://ideone.com/Rcm5uI  -> working fine for set of inputs

Comment: So why it is showing null .What may be the reason

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You are defining the `BufferReader` as `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));` and reading `String` as `br.readLine();`.

This snippet works absolutely fine and prints the input string back to the console:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
}
```

Some of the possibilities where you can get errors:

1. StringTokenizer

   ```
   StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
   ```

   Before passing it to the `StringTokenizer` make sure that you get a String back from `br.readLine()`.

   ```
   String text = br.readLine();
   if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
       StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
       /* Rest of the code */
   }
   ```
2. Loop Condition Variable

   ```
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   ```

   I do not see anything for `BufferedReader` which initializes `n`. Make sure you initialize it correctly.

Here is a quick code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    long j, n, f, mm = 1000000007;
    int i, x;
    BigInteger u, sum, temp, m;
    BigInteger[] a = new BigInteger[100009];  long[] b=new long[100009];

    Scanner har = new Scanner(System.in);

    long t = har.nextInt();
    for(f=0;f<t;f++)
    {   
        temp = BigInteger.valueOf(1);   
        sum = BigInteger.valueOf(0);    
        u = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
        n = har.nextInt();    
        x = har.nextInt(); 
        m = har.nextBigInteger();

        /* Goto Next Line */
        har.nextLine();

        /* Start Reading Line */
        String text = har.nextLine();
        System.out.println("String Value: " + text);
        if(null != text) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text);
            for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                b[i] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                System.out.println("Value of b[" + i + "] = " + b[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting error when i am splitting the string into the tokens which i need as input to the array

Comment: Check if `br.readLine()` is not `null` before passing it to your tokenizer.

Comment: n is the value scanned from the user . I have scanner to take value of n

Comment: You should use only one i.e. either `Scanner` or the `BufferedReader` at a time. Is there any specific reason that you need both of them together?

Comment: Yes i have to take value of m as a biginteger

Comment: `fast input` What does that even mean?